# What is the analytic representation of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ a^nx^n}{n!}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I only know that a geometric series is $$\frac1{1-x}\qquad (|x|<1)$$ and this looks similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

> $$
> e^{z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!},\quad z \in \mathbb{C}.
> $$

You may put $z:=a x$ then $z^n=a^nx^n$ giving
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n x^n}{n!}=e^{ax}.
$$

Comment: what about the constant a?

Comment: @grayQuant See the last equality. Thanks.